# What's MySQL's role in a JPA project?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jpa

I am confused about MySQL's role within a JPA project. For instance, if the project is being made in eclipse IDE, how can this be exported in MySQL? What's MySQL's role in this project? I have researched about this, but I still need some clarification.

Comment: MySQL is a DB, it just stores data. If you have doubts like these (confusing an IDE with a database), IMO you should try some more basic technologies (like JDBC) before going into JPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's MySQL's role in this project?

MySQL is the database: where the data is stored.  That's what its role is.

You typically don't need to "export" anything to MySQL from your project.  Rather, you set up the JPA configuration file with the backend database settings (database type, hostname, account name, logical database name, etc), and the JPA provider (for example Hibernate) takes care of creating the necessary tables and indexes in your backend database.

Answer (score 2):

JPA is a specification that describes how to save Java objects (called entities) in a database. MySQL is one of many databases a JPA provider can use. You'll specify the database connection at runtime (often in a properties file), and you can generally configure your provider for different databases.

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) is database management system, meaning it let's you store and query the data in handy manner. [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/home/newcomers.php) is devepolment enviroment that helps programmers to create software. [JPA](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077817/java-se/understanding-jpa-part-1-the-object-oriented-paradigm-of-data-persistence.html) is a standard for ORM that let's you map data from the database on the objects (f.e. in Java). There is little connection between these 3.

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/), as your research should have told you, is a database (where you store data in a tabular form).

[Java Persistence API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html) is an API that handles the mapping between data in a tabular format and an objects as used in a Java program.

This process is know as [Object Relational Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).

The database is typically created from a set of scripts, so there's not normally an export process, although some JPA implementations such as [Hibernate have a pretty good go at creating the database for you](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch21.html#toolsetguide-s1) based on the mappings to object model without the need for you to write any database scripts.